# Uncaught TypeError: with .animate() using hammer.js 1.0.10 with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova-3, zepto, hammer.js

I'm currently developing a cordova(3.4.0) app for fun.

The version of `hammer.js` is `1.0.10`

The version of `zepto.js` is `1.1.3`

Here are all my .js I'm using in my index.html after I read all the dependancy et doc:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

`slider.js` is the JavaScript where i'm using hammer, I called it after in `index.js`

***index.js*** :

```
onDeviceReady: function(e)
  {
    slider(e);
  },
```

so

***slider.js*** :

```
function slider($)
  {
    var sidebar = 0;
    var page = document.getElementById('profiles_view');
    Hammer(page).on("swiperight", function(e)
      {
        if (sidebar)
          {
            return true;
          }
      alert("swipe right!");
      page.animate({translateX: "240px"}, 200);
      sidebar = 1;
      })

    Hammer(page).on("swipeleft", function(e)
      {
        if (!sidebar)
          {
           return true;
          }
       page.animate({translateX: "0px"}, 200);
        sidebar = 0;
      })
  }(Zepto);
```

the plugin hammer detect the different movement since I got the alert box working

but, I'm encountering a problem when I called :

```
page.animate({translateX: "0px"}, 200);
```

or

```
page.animate({translateX: "0px"}, 200);
```

The dev tool says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

the complete error log is :

```
  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function slider.js:18
     (anonymous function) slider.js:18
     s.proxy zepto.js:2
     (anonymous function) zepto.js:2
     (anonymous function) zepto.js:2
     n.fn.each zepto.js:2
     t.fn.trigger zepto.js:2
     Hammer.Instance.trigger jquery.hammer.js:73
     swipeGesture hammer.js:1328
     triggerGesture hammer.js:925
     each hammer.js:146
     detect hammer.js:921
     bindDomOnTouch hammer.js:650
     (anonymous function) jquery.hammer.js:43
     s.proxy zepto.js:2
```

I don't really know what is wrong 
ans since I tried everything and searched everywhere (I'm a newbie)

I really count on someone kind enough to help me with this

Thank you in advance.

EDIT :
I found the solution trying different thing , so if somebody got the same mistake :

change

**index.js :**

```
onDeviceReady: function()
 {
   slider();
 },
```

and

**slider.js :**

```
function slider()
  {
    var sidebar = 0;
    var $page = $('#' + "profile_view");
    $page.hammer().on("swiperight", function(event)
      {
        if (sidebar)
          {
            return true;
          }
      alert("swipe right!");
      $page.animate({translateX: "240px"}, 200);
      sidebar = 1;
      })

    .on("swipeleft", function(event)
      {
        if (!sidebar)
          {
           return true;
          }
       $page.animate({translateX: "0px"}, 200);
       sidebar = 0;
      })
  }(Zepto);
```

have a good day !